# How do I create a Live Stream M3U8 from Already Hosted MP4 Videos?

Tags: http-live-streaming, m3u8, iptv

I'd much appreciate if anyone could help me create

Here is an example of how I create my m3u8 files

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1,Home Video 1
http://linktomymp4homevideogoeshere.com
#EXTINF:-1,Home Video 2
http://linktomymp4homevideogoeshere.com
```

So How can I make this M3U8 Playlist a Live Stream for a program like VLC Player?

Basically How can I make a live stream of a m3u8 playlist file which has already hosted mp4 videos, and it loops to go to the first video after it's finished cycling through the last video on the list?

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Comment: Hello, I'm using windows 10, and I code with notepad ++

Answer (score 0):

First of all HLS does not support MP4, it only supports MPEG-2 Transport Streams. They have recently added support for *fragmented MP4*. You can use ffmpeg to convert mp4 files to mpegts by simple command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb output.ts
```

You can statically create a simple playlist like

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:13
#EXTINF:13.0,
1.ts
#EXTINF:13.0,
2.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Loop is a player property, there is no HLS tag defined in HLS draft https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-20#section-4.3.4.2 to start playing again from beginning.